# Laravel - Search two tables in one query

Tags: laravel

I have a ajax search box which searches in one table. I want it to expand search to another table as well:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $output="";
        $files = File::where('id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->get();
        if($files)
        {
            foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
                $output.='<tr>'.
                '<td><a href=/files/'. $file->id. '>View '. $file->id. '</a></td>'.
                '<td>'.$file->customer->name.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$file->vehicle_id.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$file->job_status.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$file->job_status_note.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$file->file_status.'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    return Response($output);
}
```

If you notice in the for loop, I am pulling customer name based on an id.

```
        '<td>'.$file->customer->name.'</td>'.
```

This particular table stores customer ID. I have put a relationship to customer (customer has many files / File belong to one customer). I was trying to expand my search as well to customer table.

This is how I tried it -

```
    $files = File::where('id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orWhere('customer->name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->get();
```

seems to be not working. What am I doing wrong?
Jist: I want to take keyword and search if that suits to a customer name.

Answer (score 0):

In File Model define a relationship to customer.
I believe customer has many files and file has a one customer, so.

You are looking for is `orWhereHas()` function.

this function checks whether that there is a relationship exists that satisfies the given conditions.

```
class File extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

use the relationship to filter results.

```
$files = File::where('id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('customer', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: The first part of code searches by id. When second part comes it does not search anything.  - ->orWhereHas('customer', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
    }) --

Comment: But this is the concept. find what are the other missing parts. (define the correct relationship with correct foreign keys, define foreign keys in database table)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, make sure you have something like this within your `File` model:

```
class File extends Model
{
  public function customer()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
  }
}
```

After that, you can use something like this to obtain them all:

```
$files = File::leftJoin('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'files.customer_id')
         ->where('id','LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')
         ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(`customers`.`name`)'), 'LIKE', '%'. strtolower($request->search).'%')
         ->get();
```

Comment: The query should work just fine. The issue might be related to lower case / upper case names. I'll update it